# I'm just interested in buddhism

Tags: prayer, buddha

Do buddhists pray? Do they ever speak to the universe in a spiritual manner? What are buddhists views on suicide? Do you help plan out your life before being reincarnated?

Comment: This looks like 3 questions - please post separately to get more detailed answers.

Comment: To be honest this is too broad for me. I would be in favour of closing unless OP is willing to break this down into other questions or tighten up this question

Comment: Would you like this to be understood as a single question, for example, "Do Buddhists pray, suicide, and then hope to be reincarnated with a life they pre-planned?" Or were you asking it more as three separate questions, i.e. about prayer, suicide, and planning before reincarnation? Also if there is a specific [school of Buddhism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schools_of_Buddhism#Classifications) that you're interested in, then mention which of the schools you're asking about (it's also OK to ask questions without specifying a school).

Comment: This person is new so why not answer these according to the order given?

Answer (score 2):

So this is your questions: Do buddhists pray? Do they ever speak to the universe in a spiritual manner? What are buddhists views on suicide? Do you help plan out your life before being reincarnated?

1) Do buddhists pray?

> yes we pray.

2) Do they ever speak to the universe in a spiritual manner?

> Um, not to the universe, a universe is a science thing (which is actually existed outside of the earth. So rather just say "Heaven". 
>   We usually pray in our prayer to wish for the Heaven and let the wish go to the heaven and we believe something good will happen to us.

3) What are buddhists views on suicide?

> We believe someone who suicided will have to recycle in their another ten lifes - will end each of their life by suicides. 
>   But nowadays, I think people don't take it too much.

4) Do you help plan out your life before being reincarnated?

> should say yes, I also believe being reincarnated is because of that thing - planning out a life or wishing to have something they have before. (means) They just can't leave their previous life and want to hold on it in any possible ways...

P.S: maybe my answers are not complete but I tried to let you know the basic things I wish I knew. Hope you find smth in it.